# How to set an attached property programmatically eg. Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterialProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I'd like to know how to programmatically set the WPF Dependecy Property Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterialProperty .

In the xaml I would use:

```
<Viewport2DVisual3D>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
        <MeshGeometry3D Positions = "0,0,0 0,-30.9274,0 0,-30.9274,-24.4287 0,0,-24.4287"
                        TextureCoordinates = "0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"
                        TriangleIndices = "0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
        <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"/>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource BG}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
</Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

But how can it be done in code behind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's fairly simple

just give the DiffuseMaterial a name

```
<Viewport2DVisual3D>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0,0,0 0,-30.9274,0 0,-30.9274,-24.4287 0,0,-24.4287"
                        TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"
                        TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3" />
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="diffuse" />
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource BG}" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
</Viewport2DVisual3D>
```

in code

set it like this

```
diffuse.SetValue(Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterialProperty, true);
```

or

```
Viewport2DVisual3D.SetIsVisualHostMaterial(diffuse, true);
```

the property `Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterialProperty` is an attached property which can be set in the above mentioned ways

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add a set of Viewport2DVisual3D objects at runtime so I "translated" the other instructions in C# but couldn't find out how to set that particoular property...