# How do I set ListView's `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode` in codebehind?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

I want to customize a `ListView`'s `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode` from codebehind. How can I do this?

It is easy in XAML:

```xml
<ListView
    x:Name="MyListView"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <!-- ...-->
</ListView>
```

But how could I do this in C# or C++/CX codebehind?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ScrollViewer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer?view=winrt-19041) properties (like `VerticalScrollMode`, `VerticalScrollBarVisibility`, etc) are [attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/attached-properties-overview) (just like [AutomationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.AutomationProperties?view=winrt-19041) are).

XAML actually provides [two methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/attached-properties-overview#attached-properties-in-code) of setting these properties:

- The property system (`SetValue` and `GetValue`)
- The XAML accessor pattern

I find the `SetValue` pattern super straightforward:

```cpp
// C++/CX
this->MyListView->SetValue(ScrollViewer::VerticalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode::Disabled);
this->MyListView->SetValue(ScrollViewer::VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility::Hidden);
this->MyListView->SetValue(ScrollViewer::HorizontalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode::Disabled);
this->MyListView->SetValue(ScrollViewer::HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility::Hidden);
```

(I have not used the other pattern).

This method works for all AttachedProperties (see [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571504/how-to-set-an-attached-property-programmatically-eg-viewport2dvisual3d-isvisual)).

---

This works because attached properties are, at their core, DependencyProperties, which provide the `SetValue` and `GetValue` APIs. From the documentation of attached properties:

> Attached properties for the Windows Runtime are implemented as dependency properties, so that the values can be stored in the shared dependency-property store by the property system. Therefore attached properties expose a dependency property identifier on the owning class.