# How do you set WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome in specific button programatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

I have a custom title bar and I used WindowChrome.

In order to make the buttons clickable, I have to set `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` to `true`, that's simple on xaml.

`<Button x:Name="MyButton" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="true" />`

However, how can I do the same programmatically?

By default, I have to set the `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` into `false` then it needs to be set to true later in the code.

I tried `MyButton.IsHitTestVisible = true;` but this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set an attached property programmatically eg. Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterialProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571504/how-to-set-an-attached-property-programmatically-eg-viewport2dvisual3d-isvisual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would set the `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` attached property of `MyButton` programmatically:

```
System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome.SetIsHitTestVisibleInChrome(MyButton, true);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: This is exactly what is in duplicated question's answer ...